# What spreadsheet apps for the iPad support checkboxes/toggle buttons?

Tags: ipad, applications

I'm looking for a spreadsheet app that fills in a functionality hole in Google Docs, specifically the ability to have checkboxes/toggle buttons or equivalent.  The only problem is I will probably only use this once or twice so I have second thoughts about spending $10 for Numbers, even though I'm pretty sure it would do what I want.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

I would like to be able to import work already done in Google Docs, but I'm fine with doing a manual export/import if it saves money.

Comment: Good point (though not sure about the dinner analogy).  I've edited the subject to make it more correct - my question changed in the writing and I didn't think to update the subject.  Cheers.

Comment: My sense of humor is often vague and brief - but I mean it as humor :-) - great edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would really go with [numbers](http://www.apple.com/apps/numbers/), I can say from experience that It will allow you to use check boxes, radio buttons etc.

You would be able to export a Google doc to an excel file and then open in numbers.

If you do choose to export a Google Doc file into an excel file you could also use dropbox to open and edit it in another office based app, with that you may be able to use checks and radio buttons, as long as they already exist in the doc.

A very good solution is [Quick office](http://www.quickoffice.com/)

You can also try a lot of other free office tools such as [Docs Free Mobile Office](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/documents-free-mobile-office/id306273816?mt=8)